# got TypeError when running linear regression with tensorflow. ' Op has type float64 that does not match type float32 of argument'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm pretty new to tensorflow. I did a linear regression with tensorflow. 
when I ran the codes below, I got typeError like this:

TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float64 that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'.

Spent hours but could not figure out why. 
where did it go wrong?  help is very much appreciated. thanks a lot.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

training_epoch = 1000
display_epoch=50
learning_rate = 0.01
train_X = np.asarray([3.3,4.4,5.5,6.71,6.93,4.168,9.779,6.182,7.59,2.167,
                         7.042,10.791,5.313,7.997,5.654,9.27,3.1])
train_Y = np.asarray([1.7,2.76,2.09,3.19,1.694,1.573,3.366,2.596,2.53,1.221,
                         2.827,3.465,1.65,2.904,2.42,2.94,1.3])
n_samples = train_X.shape[0]
X = tf.placeholder('float')
Y= tf.placeholder ('float')
w = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(2))
pred = tf.add(tf.mul(X,w[0]), w[1])

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)
    for epoch in range(training_epoch):
        for x, y in zip(train_X, train_Y):
            session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X:x, Y:y})
        if (epoch+1) % display_epoch == 0:
            weight = session.run(w)
            bias = session.run(b)
            cost = session.run(loss, feed_dict={X:train_X, Y:train_Y})
            print('epoch: {0:.2f}, weight: {1:.9f}. bias: {2:.9f}, cost: {3:.9f}'.format(epoch+1,weight[0], weight[1], cost))
    print('optimization complete')
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** The placeholder `X` and variable `w` have different element types, and TensorFlow does not automatically cast op arguments, so the `tf.mul()` op fails.

Your placeholder `X` has type `tf.float32` because it is defined to have dtype `'float'`, which is defined as meaning "32-bit floating point", in this line:

```
X = tf.placeholder('float')
```

Your variable `w` has type `tf.float64` because it is initialized from `np.random.randn(2)`, which has a dtype of `np.float64`, in this line:

```
w = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(2))
```

The simplest solution would be to define `w` as having type `tf.float32`:

```
w = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(2).astype(np.float32))
```

Alternatively, you could define `X` as having type `tf.float64`:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float64)
```

There is also a [`tf.cast()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#cast) op for making explicit conversions, but I wouldn't recommend using it, as it is not differentiable, and so can interfere with computing gradients.

---

PS. A more idiomatic way to do this would be to use the [`tf.random_normal()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#random_normal) op, which avoids putting large constants in the graph:

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2]))
```

Although it doesn't matter much for small variables (like a 2-element vector here), it becomes more important for much larger weight matrices.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation!